# How do I copy a specific subtitle track, by language, with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I have a video file with 30+ subtitles from which I want to save only the English subtitle track.

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Galaxy.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Galaxy.720p.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV
    COMMENT         : GalaxyTV - small excellence!
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:47:31.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 880 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : GalaxyTV - small excellence!
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:47:31.453000000

    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : GalaxyTV - small excellence!
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
      DURATION        : 00:47:31.477000000

    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : GalaxyTV - small excellence!
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.35.100 srt
      DURATION        : 00:43:46.478000000

    ...

    Stream #0:32(chi): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : Chinese Traditional
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.35.100 srt
      DURATION        : 00:45:40.508000000
```

I tried the following with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i Galaxy.mkv -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:m:language:eng mov_text out.mp4
```

But that gives the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x7fqe85422f00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'mov_text'
mov_text: Invalid argument
```

Shouldn't the option `-map 0:s:m:language:eng` select the english subtitle?
Why does FFmpeg complain it is an invalid argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov_text` is a subtitle codec and is the argument for the codec option `-c:s`.

So,

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i Galaxy.mkv -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:m:language:eng -c:s mov_text out.mp4`